# batch colorizer will close itself after a certain amount of "if's"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have made this small script for my "desktop++" program in batch and I made a page where I can adjust the colors it works till number 14: when it turns light purple till number 16 where it turns bright white the rest of the script doesn't matter or anything so I want to ask if there is a "maximum" amount of if statements in batch I will show you the script here

```
 :background
    cls
    echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    echo and what will your personal preferenced background color be today??
    echo 1 for black
    echo 2 for blue
    echo 3 for green
    echo 4 for aqua
    echo 5 for red
    echo 6 for purple
    echo 7 for yellow
    echo 8 for white
    echo 9 for gray
    echo 10 for light blue
    echo 11 for light green
    echo 12 for light aqua
    echo 13 for light red
    echo 14 for light purple
    echo 15 for light yellow
    echo 16 for bright white
    echo type back to go back
    echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    set /p bckgrnd=Color:
    if %bckgrnd%==1 (
    set backc=0
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==2 (
    set backc=1
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==3 (
    set backc=2
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==4 (
    set backc=3
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==5 (
    set backc=4
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==6 (
    set backc=5
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==7 (
    set backc=6
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==8 (
    set backc=7
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==back (
    goto :extracolor
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==9 (
    set backc=8
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==10 (
    set backc=9
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==11 (
    set backc=a
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==12 (
    set backc=b
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==13 (
    set backc=c
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%=14 (
    set backc=d
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==15 (
    set backc=e
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    if %bckgrnd%==16 (
    set backc=f
    color %backc%%currentcolor%
    goto :background
    )
    goto :background
```

also I am fairly new to programming and mostly in batch programming so if you have any feedback about my script it'd be greatly appreciated since I am not planning on publishing this (personal use) because it's really to learn batch nothing more :D hope you guys can help because I've used this site many times to solve my problems and i wanted to use this to ask a question on my own since I've not found anything around this topic

Comment: Find the difference between your `if .. 13` and `if ... 14`, try an accurate compare

Answer (score 4):

The error is the IF-statement for 14:

```
if %bckgrnd%=14 (
```

You have used a single equality sign instead of double, so it should be

```
if %bckgrnd%==14 (
```

But even if you would correct that, you'll see your program won't work as how you want it to work. Maybe you noticed that each time you enter a value, it will only change the colors the next time you entered a value. That's due to the fact each IF-block (from the opening `(` to its closing `)`) will be treated as a whole, as if it was one single command (as if you would have written it on one line). And it is not possible to assign a new value to a variable (with `set` ) and use that new value in the same command (you use it each time in the `color` command). Actually there is a way but it isn't needed here, I will add a link at the end of my answer. The way we're going to solve this is by following the advice I'll give you in the following paragraph.

As you may see in your code, all your IF-blocks (except the one for "back") do the same thing: they set the variable `backc`, call the `color` command and jump to the same label with `goto`. In programming it is advised to put as less possible code in IF-blocks. Put only the differences in the IF-blocks and put the ressemblances after all IF-blocks. You can replace each one of your IF-blocks by IF-blocks of this form:

```
IF "%bckgrnd%" == "<number>" (
    set back=<new_value>
    goto :commonPart
)
```

Replace `<number>` and `<new_value>` according to the case and after all your IF-blocks you can then add the `:commonPart` label and put the common code under it:

```
:commonPart
color %backc%%currentcolor%
goto :background
```

You may have noticed 2 things:

1. the problem about reading the variable in the IF-block is now gone, we read the value outside the IF-block and solved the problem.
2. I surrounded each part of the comparison in IF-clauses with double quotes ("). This is very important because if a user just presses Enter the first time  without giving any value or just gives whitespaces, your `bckgrnd` variable will be empty or contain only whitespaces and each `IF %bckgrnd%==<number> (` will result in `IF ==<number> (` or something like `IF   ==<number> (` which the command interpreter won't be able to understand and will return an error. With the double quotes it will give `IF "" == "<number>" (` (or `IF "   " == "<number>" (` ) and see you at least gave something: the double quotes (but don't forget the double quotes arround the right part, the number, as well. As [@aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) mentionned, each time a user just presses enter without giving any value, the variable `bckgrnd` actually will keep its precedent value and remain unchanged. So it is only at the beginning the variable could remain empty

That's pretty much all I can give as advice for the moment. For the rest I noticed some variable and label that you use but are not in the code you provided: `currentcolor` used when you try to change the color and the label `extracolor` in the case `if "%bckgrnd%"=="back" (`. I assume the code you gave above is not the complete script you had so far so I cannot help where you're using these. Espacially where you use the variable to change the color...if you did not already, please check how you should use the `color`-command (simply type `color /?` in a command prompt)

Finally this is what the endresult of the code you provided should look like:

```
@echo off
:background
cls
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo and what will your personal preferenced background color be today??
echo 1 for black
echo 2 for blue
echo 3 for green
echo 4 for aqua
echo 5 for red
echo 6 for purple
echo 7 for yellow
echo 8 for white
echo 9 for gray
echo 10 for light blue
echo 11 for light green
echo 12 for light aqua
echo 13 for light red
echo 14 for light purple
echo 15 for light yellow
echo 16 for bright white
echo type back to go back
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
set /p bckgrnd=Color:
if "%bckgrnd%" == "1" (
    set backc=0
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "2" (
    set backc=1
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "3" (
    set backc=2
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "4" (
    set backc=3
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "5" (
    set backc=4
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "6" (
    set backc=5
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "7" (
    set backc=6
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "8" (
    set backc=7
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "back" (
    goto :extracolor
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "9" (
    set backc=8
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "10" (
    set backc=9
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "11" (
    set backc=a
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "12" (
    set backc=b
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "13" (
    set backc=c
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "14" (
    set backc=d
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "15" (
    set backc=e
    goto :commonPart
)
if "%bckgrnd%" == "16" (
    set backc=f
    goto :commonPart
)

:commonPart
color %backc%%currentcolor%
goto :background
```

Before I wish you good luck, I would like to mention that you can actually simplify your code even more because if you look closely, all of the remaining code inside the IF-clauses have the same logic: `backc=backgrnd - 1` in hexadecimal form (except for the "back" case). If you have the same logic, you can (and actually must) replace all these IF-clauses by some code just executing that logic. Not only in batch but also in other languages as well. [geisterfurz007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40735811/7170434) has provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40735811/7170434) just below where all if-clauses are replaced by a "special advanced trick" producing that logic for your case. You'll see it will reduce your code a lot.

Good luck!!

PS: the other solution to the problem of the IF-clause is called delayed expansion. You can easily enable it: here is a [link](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) that shows how and repeats a little bit why. Googling it might give you some more info too.

Comment: Actually a variable is not going to be cleared but remains unchanged in case the user just presses enter at a `set /P` prompt... The code could still be extensively simplified, because there is a relationship between the values of `bckgrnd` and `backc`...

Comment: Yes you are right. I'll edit my post right away. Thank you very much!

Comment: For the simplifications it is true, the code above could seriously be simplified but because I didn't know what the reason was he was using IF-blocks, I let it as it was. For eg. we had to train a lot with IF-clauses at school before learning how to simplify them. But again, you're right...I at least could have mentionned it! Thanks!

Comment: @J.Baoby I have made a more or less simpler version down below to point on ;) And he said that he has just started with programming. In batch the way to get from decimal to hexadecimal is not easy to come up with and a case does not really exist.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 thanks, I won't forget to mention this too :)

Comment: thank you so much and i will also thank the comment posted before :D it's a begginers mistake so i can accept that! thanks again!

Comment: before i go i got one thing to say i saw you in the comments of this post saying about learning programming in school. that is the exact reason i started we will learn programming whenever we're 15 years old and you MAY drop it the year after if you want so when you're 16 you will finnaly learn "programming" but these teachers have no idea what they're doing, they don't even know what batch means and now they're making a "website with yellow background and blue letters" what i think is on my limit, yes it is a bit young to start with my age but i want to become a programmer.. had no more space

Comment: It's our pleasure @Juggler.  It is quite enjoyable to hear such motivation. It is true the "programming" (or what is called "programming") is a bit poor in some educational systems. I remember when I was in college the topics in our "programming" course were Excel and Word (good old times :) even though I'm not that old haha ). I can surely tell you you're on the right path. Stay motivated and don't hesitate to ask questions, we're here to help (and pleased to also)!    Good luck!! or should I say: "Veel succes ermee" ;)

Comment: .. you looked at my profile didn't you or should i say, nee ik weet niet wat ik moet zeggen, voordat ik ga had ik nog een vraag. Programmeren in word hadden jullie geen notepad of fijner notepad++ en naast dat had ik nog een vraag ik ben heel erg slecht met andere talen zoals op mijn profiel staan, maar hoe maak je echt je eigen programma. Hiermee bedoel ik hoe je geen cmd.exe start zoals in batch maar je eigen "program window" welke taal zou je aanraden? bedankt nogmaals!

Comment: Not really...you added in your question you were dutch! We programmeerden niet echt in Word of Excel. We leerden toen in onze les "Informatica" hoe we een deftig Word-document enzo konden maken. Het was toen nog echt speciaal! Je tweede vraag is wel een beetje "moeilijk" te beantwoorden. Ik ga dan wel terug naar het engels. Misschien hebben andere mensen noch interessante tips voor je ;)

Comment: The question: "what is the most best language to start with when creating applications?" is not easy to answer... I think Java is the easiest way to start. Especially with JavaFX you can easily build graphical designs (GUIs). But you need to get handy with Java before attacking JavaFX. I can maybe give you [this](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java) interactive tuto to start with Java. Many other tutorials on the net (like the [official Oracle tuto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)) and  books (like [this one](http://www.bluej.org/objects-first/)) exist as well.

Answer (score 0):

To heavily simplify your code you could do the following:
As you are basically subtracting 1 from the input and changing the value to its hexadecimal opponent there is a way in batch of doing that reducing your massive if-construction.

```
set /p backgrd= Preffered Background:
if "x%backgrd"=="xback" Goto back
set /a backgrd=backgrd-1
call cmd /c exit /b %backgrd%
set hexbackgrd=%=exitcode%
set hexbackgrd=%hexbackgrd:0=%
color %hexbackgrd%%currentcolor%
```

What does this actually do?!

With `set /p`you are reading in a value as you do already.
`set /a` will perform an **A**rithemtic action; in this case a simple subtraction.
The magic happens in the next line: `call cmd /c exit /b %backgrd%`
This will run the command `exit /b %backgrd%` in another "virtual" cmd window and exit it with the exit code with the value of `%backgrd%`.
You can get this value (now in hex) using `set hexbackgrd=%=exitcode%`. Notice the `=` within the percentage signs! If you leave it out an error will be thrown.
Now `%hexbackgrd%` looks like this `0000000C`. To remove the leading zeroes the next command is used.
It sets hexbackgrd to the value of hexbackgrd with all 0=
At last you can set your new color to the value of your freshly generated background value and the current font color.

Feel free to ask any questions :)

Comment: a small question i don't understand the part where you said set /a and the call part so my question is what does set /a do and what does call do i know what the call command does but not how it works. because yes, i can easily copy the code and deal with it but i'd like to learn a little more than just copying thanks for your respond and already thanks for responding back tho you haven't replied yet! :)

Comment: Well I guess you know what `set` does. The additional switch `/a` is needed to treat the term after the equal sign as an arithmetic function/calculation. Difference: `set foo=1+1 echo foo -> 1+1` vs. `set /a foo=1+1 echo foo -> 2` (Untested due to leak of Laptop during bus ride tho). `call` can be used in two ways: 1) Jump to a declares label within the same script and jump back when the end of the file is reached (like a function basically). 2) Start an exe (cmd.exe in our case) and wait until it is closed (try with notepad.exe for example. Cmd line will close only after closing the notepad.

Comment: You are doing the same with kind if an internal cmd window you are opening with the command that tells to set the exitcode to the value you desire. As the exitvalue always is written and read as hexadecimal number, this is used to convert from decimal to hex. Usually the exitcode is used to determine possible errors and commandline programs sometimes come with an extra handsheet to interprete the exitcodes correctly (0-> ran currectly, 1-> value to high etc.)

Comment: i tried /a on school today (really simple) i made a counter this is what it looked like simplified (i made it for fun because we don't program in school) :top set /a lol=%lol% +1 ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w >NUL goto :top

Comment: btw when i read this back that "real simple part" is about how simple the script is not the command ;)

Answer (score 0):

hello everybody that is seeing this post right now, yes i've  seen these comments and used them but i wanted to come up with something on my own for fun. This is a script wich makes it alot easier you can do this by having just 2 columns of the same thing and it worked great tho i'd suggest you use the ones on top, i just found it hard to understand them. So this is for noobs like me :)

```
:background
cls
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo and what will your personal preferenced background color be today??
echo 1 for black
echo 2 for blue
echo 3 for green
echo 4 for aqua
echo 5 for red
echo 6 for purple
echo 7 for yellow
echo 8 for white
echo 9 for 
echo 10 for light blue
echo a for light green
echo b for light aqua
echo c for light red
echo d for light purple
echo e for light yellow
echo f for bright white
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
set /p background=Color:
color %background%%foreground%
goto :background
```

also here is for people that just want to copy paste the foreground:

```
:foreground
cls
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo and what will your personal preferenced foreground color be today??
echo 1 for black
echo 2 for blue
echo 3 for green
echo 4 for aqua
echo 5 for red
echo 6 for purple
echo 7 for yellow
echo 8 for white
echo 9 for gray
echo 10 for light blue
echo a for light green
echo b for light aqua
echo c for light red
echo d for light purple
echo e for light yellow
echo f for bright white
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
set /p foreground=Color:
color %background%%foreground%
goto :foreground
```

hoped this whole post helped you all i ofcourse don't take credit for the comments that've been post by amazing people be sure to thank them! and i want to thank you for seeing this post and good luck with your scripts!

Comment: haha i am so funny  i needed to say 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 and not 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10